How to use Japanese IME on input type decimal input mask jquery
Here is my input mask code which I am initializing in a drawcallback function.
$(".clstxtInputNumber").inputmask({
    alias: 'decimal',
    groupSeparator: ',',
    autoGroup: true,
    digits: gDomesticOverseas == "M" ? 0 : 2,
    digitsOptional: false,
    rightAlign: false
});

I want to convert the values double bytes values i-e Japanese IME keypad layout into single bytes values
Here is my input element
<input maxLength='15' " + enableDisable + " oninput='javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength)'  id='" + ControlId + "'  style='max-width: 300px!important;' type=\"text\" name=\"fname\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm form-control-solid mb-4 mb-lg-0 customInputField clstxtInputText clstxtInputNumber clsRightAlignColumn\" onkeypress='return isNumberWithDoubleByte(event)' value='" + data + "' />

I want to apply onkeypress function which will convert the double bytes into single byte,
Is there any way to do this.
this function runs when I comment the inputmask and then it shows perfectly fine values while using english keyboard.
function DoubleToSingleBytesConversion(ele) {
    debugger
    var currentValue = $(ele).val();
    currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll(',', '');
    var regex = /^\d+(\.\d*)?$/;
    if (currentValue !== "") {

        if (currentValue.includes('０')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('０', '0');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('１')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('１', '1');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('２')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('２', '2');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('３')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('３', '3');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('４')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('４', '4');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('５')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('５', '5');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('６')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('６', '6');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('７')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('７', '7');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('８')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('８', '8');
        }
        if (currentValue.includes('９')) {
            currentValue = currentValue.replaceAll('９', '9');
        }
        if (currentValue.length > parseInt($(ele).attr('maxlength'))) {
            currentValue = currentValue.slice(0, parseInt($(ele).attr('maxlength')))
        }
        if (regex.test(currentValue)) {

            tempVal = currentValue;
            tempVal = parseFloat(tempVal).toFixed(2);
            tempVal = ConvertToDigitsWithComma(tempVal)

            $(ele).val(tempVal);
        }
        else {
            currentValue = currentValue.replace(/[^\d,.]/g, '');
            tempVal = currentValue;

            tempVal = parseFloat(tempVal).toFixed(2);
            tempVal = ConvertToDigitsWithComma(tempVal)

            $(ele).val(tempVal);
        }

    }
    else {
        // $(ele).val("0.00");
    }
}

function ConvertToDigitsWithComma(txt) {
    if (txt instanceof Element || txt instanceof HTMLDocument) {
        let value = txt.value.replace(/,/g, ''); // Remove existing commas, if any
        // Convert the value to a comma-separated format
        let formattedValue = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        // Update the input element's value with the formatted value
        txt.value = formattedValue;
    } else {
        let formattedValue = txt.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return formattedValue
    }
    // Return false to prevent any default behavior or propagation
    return false;
}

I have create the above function. When I debug using browser console this function shows exactly the same values but when I don't apply debugger it will show values like:

what I type : "100000.00"
what input shows : "1100010.00"

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
